# Swift 3 xcode storyboard, add box-shadow to UIView, like a CSS style box-shadow

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, storyboard

As you can see, I would like to add a shadow around the edges of each UIView in the cells as white on gray hard to see it's borders clearly.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Set your view's shadow properties to add a shadow.

#### SWIFT 3

```
YourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
YourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
YourView.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
YourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
```

**NOTE:** replace YourView with the view you want shadow.

Comment: What do I replace in the "YourView"?

Comment: replace `YourView` to your view which you want to give shadow.

Comment: How can I define what "YourView" is? I built everything in storyboard.

Comment: you have created your table view cell class. for the cells you created in the tableview in storyboard. so connect all your views using `IBOutlet` in you tableview cell class. there you can get `YourView`

Comment: Please. I need guidelines. Not theory. I have no idea what I'm suppose to do.

Comment: Looks neat with those parameters, @BhautikZiniya, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

here is my approach to this:

You create a new class called `ShadowView`.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ShadowView: UIView {
    //Shadow
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            self.updateView()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            self.updateView()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3) {
        didSet {
            self.updateView()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 15.0 {
        didSet {
            self.updateView()
        }
    }

    //Apply params
    func updateView() {        
        self.layer.shadowColor = self.shadowColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = self.shadowOpacity
        self.layer.shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = self.shadowRadius
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this class for you view in the storyboard like:

[image: storyboard 1]

Now you can edit the values in the attributes inspector:

[image: storyboard 2]

Answer (score 2):

You can select opacity as you want.

```
override func awakeFromNib() 
{
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOffset =  CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)   // CGSizeMake(0, 1)
        self.viewContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.viewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.65
        self.viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 1
        self.viewContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        self.viewContainer.layer.masksToBounds = false       
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
```

Comment: In cell class there will be awakefromnib ,copy and paste this code there or replace that method with this

Comment: Not sure where cell class is either.

Comment: You made a class for your cell in storyboard

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you typed some elaborative answers and instructions.

Comment: This method itself is enough for ios developer. I am not sure if you used tableview cell before. 
Go to cellForRowAtIndexPath -> ctrl + click on your cell -> put this method there.

Comment: Did you find Cell class ?

Comment: Oh you made static cells, You have to create one class from UITableviewCell like you create View controller and then you can do this. Wait i'll update my answers with screenshots